# Adicionar itens em listbox

Tags: vba, listbox

Boa tarde, gente

é uma pergunta bem besta, pois estou iniciando na programação em vba e não estou conseguindo corrigir esse erro. Agradeço se alguém conseguir me ajudar
Gostaria de preencher um listbox com três colunas em que o título das colunas são :
Critério, Distribuição e Variação
A primeira coluna serão preenchidas com : e1, e2, e3, ... e10 (10 linhas)
A segunda coluna será preenchido com o texto "uniforme" para todas as linhas
A terceira coluna será preenchido com o valor "10" para todas as linhas

No entanto, só estou conseguindo atribuir o valor do título da primeira coluna. Quando tento adicionar o título da segunda o seguinte erro é exibido:
Não foi possível definir a propriedade List. Índice de matriz de propriedade inválido. vba

A propriedade ColumnCount foi setada como 3

o código que eu estava tentando era o seguinte:

```
    With Me.lstbxCritEst
    .AddItem
    .List(0, 0) = "Critério"
    .List(1, 0) = "Distribuição"  ' o erro ocorre nessa linha
    .List(2, 0) = "Variação"
  End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar, sua pergunta não é besta.

Em segundo lugar, seu código deu erro em ".List(1, 0) = "Distribuição", porque o posicionamento da linha e da coluna em .List está invertido (o certo é (0,1)).

Em terceiro lugar, o que está faltando no seu código é uma estrutura de repetição que passe por todas as linhas preenchidas na planilha e leve esses valores para a listbox.

Como primeiro passo, nas propriedades da ListBox, dado que ela precisará ter três colunas, é interessante preencher com valor "3" no campo "ColumnCount":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já a minha planilha, eu montei da seguinte maneira, considerando as informações que você forneceu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por fim, a minha sugestão de código é a seguinte, o qual eu inseri em um botão ActiveX:

```
Private Sub btExecutaII_Click()

'Declara as variáveis
Dim W       As Worksheet
Dim UltCel  As Range
Dim A       As Integer
Dim Ln      As Integer

'Atribui à variável W o nome da aba da planilha (Lista, nesse caso)
Set W = Sheets("Lista")

'Seleciona a a aba Lista e, em seguida, seleciona a célula A1
W.Select
W.Range("A1").Select

'Atribui à variável UltCel o valor da última linha preenchida na coluna A
Set UltCel = W.Cells(W.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

'Limpa a ListBox, para qual eu atribuí o nome de Listagem (o nome padrão é ListBox1)
Listagem.Clear

'Atribui os valores 0 e 1 às variaveis A e Ln, respectivamente
A = 0
Ln = 1

'Cria uma estrutura de repetição para preencher a ListBox com os valores de cada linha preenchida nas colunas A,B e C
Do While A <= UltCel.Row

    With Listagem
    
        .AddItem
        .List(A, 0) = W.Cells(Ln, 1).Value
        .List(A, 1) = W.Cells(Ln, 2).Value
        .List(A, 2) = W.Cells(Ln, 3).Value
    
    End With
    
    Ln = Ln + 1
    A = A + 1
    
Loop

'Esvazia as variáveis A, Ln e UltCel
A = Empty
Ln = Empty
UltCel = Empty

MsgBox "Pronto!", vbOKOnly, "Status"



End Sub
```

O resultado esperado é esse aqui:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer dúvida ou problema, só perguntar aqui.

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Muito obrigada, Andréa!!! O problema era exatamente esse. Inverti os índices da linha com o da coluna! Por isso estava ocorrendo aquela mensagem de erro. Seu código ajudou bastante. Obrigada